# Looking for a regex to find long filenames in a text file

Tags: python, regex, windows

I'm using a regex to find filenames in a text, but it's failing on filenames with spaces.

This is the regex pattern:

```
  pattern = r"([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))"
```

when run on the text (see below) it only detects the last part of the filenames only:

['NL-RtSA_999-09_1955B3_0041.jpg', '21-11-1955.jpg', 'voorzijde.png', 'achterzijde.png']

This is the text it's scanning on:

```
0007 Willem Oliemans x Jannigje de Jong


0076 Willem Oliemans 19-01-1901 - BS Rotterdam - Overlijden 21-11-1955 - NL-RtSA_999-09_1955B3_0041.jpg
0076 Willem Oliemans 19-01-1901 - BS Rotterdam - Overlijden 21-11-1955.jpg

https://stadsarchief.rotterdam.nl/zoek-en-ontdek/archieven/zoekrestultaat-archieven/?mivast=184&miadt=184&miaet=54&micode=999-09.1955B3&minr=20800725&miview=ldt
https://www.openarch.nl/srt:c2bfa32b-d519-eb8a-c77e-e867d317998f

Gebeurtenis: Overlijden op 21 november 1955 te Rotterdam
Personen:
- Overledene > Willem Oliemans
- Vader > Jacobus Pieter Oliemans
- Moeder > Catharina Wilhelmina Duindam
- Eerder overleden echtgeno(o)t(e) > Jannigje de Jong
Bron: Stadsarchief Rotterdam, Rotterdam, BS Overlijden.
Nadere toegang op het overlijdensregister van de gemeente Rotterdam, Rotterdam, archiefnummer 999-09, inventarisnummer 1955B3, 1 januari 1955, aktenummer 1955.2389, folio b3-040v

Event: Death on 21 November 1955 in Rotterdam
Persons:
- Deceased > Willem Oliemans
- Father > Jacobus Pieter Oliemans
- Mother > Catharina Wilhelmina Duindam
- Eerder overleden echtgeno(o)t(e) > Jannigje de Jong
Source: Stadsarchief Rotterdam, Rotterdam, BS Overlijden
Nadere toegang op het overlijdensregister van de gemeente Rotterdam, Rotterdam, archive number 999-09, inventory number 1955B3, 1 January 1955, record number 1955.2389, folio b3-040v


0007 Willem Oliemans x Jannigje de Jong - 19-12-1901 - BR Rotterdam - Gezinskaart - 1 voorzijde.png
0007 Willem Oliemans x Jannigje de Jong - 19-12-1901 - BR Rotterdam - Gezinskaart - 2 achterzijde.png

0034 Jannigje de Jong 13-09-1910 - Gezinskaart Rotterdam - 1 voorzijde -
0034 Jannigje de Jong 13-09-1910 - Gezinskaart Rotterdam - 2 achterzijde -
```

I'm expecting these 4 filenames:

```
0076 Willem Oliemans 19-01-1901 - BS Rotterdam - Overlijden 21-11-1955 - NL-RtSA_999-09_1955B3_0041.jpg
0076 Willem Oliemans 19-01-1901 - BS Rotterdam - Overlijden 21-11-1955.jpg
0007 Willem Oliemans x Jannigje de Jong - 19-12-1901 - BR Rotterdam - Gezinskaart - 1 voorzijde.png
0007 Willem Oliemans x Jannigje de Jong - 19-12-1901 - BR Rotterdam - Gezinskaart - 2 achterzijde.png
```

I have tried several other regex but these didn't even detect a filename, like this one:

```
pattern = r'^[^\s]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$'
```

But I'm a total newbie at regex and while I have tested on a site like regex101, I really do not know what I am doing here.

Comment: It looks like you want to extract whole lines ending with one of the suffixes, try `(?m)^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me. Neither on regex101.

Answer (score 4):

to support spaces you should add a space to your regex like that:

```
r"([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+.\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))"
```

Comment: This works, greatly appreciated, thank you.
And s simple, I had been trying with \s....
As a follow-up; I tried adding \(\) to search for filenames with parentheses but that doesn't seem to work.
Any tips for this?

Comment: to use parentheses you must use slash:
`[\w\(\)] `

Comment: I tried that like this: [a-zA-Z0-9 _-][\w\(\)]+.\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))
but that doesn't work, neither like this:  [a-zA-Z0-9 _-\w\(\)]+.\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))
or this: [a-zA-Z0-9 _-\(\)]+.\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))

Comment: try this `[a-zA-Z0-9\(\) _-]+.\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif)`

Comment: This works, thanks again. Fiddly stuff though, had to add a . (dot) for some other variant I found while debugging, but that only worked when I put the . before the a-z, if I added the . after the - the search regex would fail.

Comment: dot in regex means `anything` and `-` is used to show a range of characters like `a-z` or `0-9`, if you want to use `-` to the exact character what you mean put a slash before it
like that:
`[a-zA-Z0-9\(\) _\-]+.\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

`^.+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ /gm`

1. `^` and `$` mark the start and the end of the line respectively
2. `.+` matches one or more characters (except line terminators)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gb5Bge/1)

Comment: Nice and short, works in Regex101 as you have shown and one of my own containing filenames with ellipses (https://regex101.com/r/3adhXw/1).
Took a bit of work to ghet it to function though, had to add: re.MULTILINE

Comment: @BigBearFreddy `/m` is the multiline flag itself